# Load lists from a text file

Tags: python, list, parsing

I have a text file with the following:

```
['Joakim Noah', 'Wilson Chandler', 'Michael Kidd-Gilchrist', 'Lance Stephenson', 'Joe Johnson', 'Blake Griffin', 'Darrell Arthur', 'Chris Paul', 'D.J. Augustin']
['Joakim Noah', 'Wilson Chandler', 'Michael Kidd-Gilchrist', 'Lance Stephenson', 'Kyle Korver', 'Blake Griffin', 'Terrence Jones', 'Chris Paul', 'Shaun Livingston']
['Joakim Noah', 'Wilson Chandler', 'Michael Kidd-Gilchrist', 'Lance Stephenson', 'Kyle Korver', 'Blake Griffin', 'Kris Humphries', 'Chris Paul', 'Jerryd Bayless']
['Joakim Noah', 'Wilson Chandler', 'Michael Kidd-Gilchrist', 'Gordon Hayward', 'Joe Johnson', 'Blake Griffin', 'Andray Blatche', 'Chris Paul', 'Jerryd Bayless']
['Joakim Noah', 'Wilson Chandler', 'Michael Kidd-Gilchrist', 'Gordon Hayward', 'Kyle Korver', 'Blake Griffin', 'Andray Blatche', 'Chris Paul', 'Avery Bradley']
```

Those are lists I've exported. I want to reimport them into another script as a list of lists. So I basically want to make a list that contains those lists. Is this possible? When I try now and read it, it reads it as a string.

Comment: You can use eval (or ast.literal_eval as pointed out by @alecxe), but more importantly, you could use [(c)pickle](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle) from both script (if both script are python…)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded
>   string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may
>   only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings,
>   numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = [literal_eval(line) for line in f]

print data
```

produces:

```
[
 ['Joakim Noah', 'Wilson Chandler', 'Michael Kidd-Gilchrist', 'Lance Stephenson', 'Joe Johnson', 'Blake Griffin', 'Darrell Arthur', 'Chris Paul', 'D.J. Augustin'], 
 ['Joakim Noah', 'Wilson Chandler', 'Michael Kidd-Gilchrist', 'Lance Stephenson', 'Kyle Korver', 'Blake Griffin', 'Terrence Jones', 'Chris Paul', 'Shaun Livingston'], 
 ['Joakim Noah', 'Wilson Chandler', 'Michael Kidd-Gilchrist', 'Lance Stephenson', 'Kyle Korver', 'Blake Griffin', 'Kris Humphries', 'Chris Paul', 'Jerryd Bayless'], 
 ['Joakim Noah', 'Wilson Chandler', 'Michael Kidd-Gilchrist', 'Gordon Hayward', 'Joe Johnson', 'Blake Griffin', 'Andray Blatche', 'Chris Paul', 'Jerryd Bayless'], 
 ['Joakim Noah', 'Wilson Chandler', 'Michael Kidd-Gilchrist', 'Gordon Hayward', 'Kyle Korver', 'Blake Griffin', 'Andray Blatche', 'Chris Paul', 'Avery Bradley']
]
```

Also, think about serializing/deserializing using [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) or [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Comment: just make sure you have full control over this text file.

Comment: @Back2Basics well, I'm not suggesting `eval()`.

Comment: @back2basis, why do you say I should have full control over this text file?

Comment: this doesn't work anymore, I copied this code and i get this error back malformed node or string:

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
    from os.path import dirname

    with open(dirname(__file__) + '/data/path/demo.txt') as input_data:
        A= [line.strip() for line in input_data.readlines()]
```

Produces:

["['Joakim Noah', 'Wilson Chandler', 'Michael Kidd-Gilchrist', 'Lance Stephenson', 'Joe Johnson', 'Blake Griffin', 'Darrell Arthur', 'Chris Paul', 'D.J. Augustin']", "['Joakim Noah', 'Wilson Chandler', 'Michael Kidd-Gilchrist', 'Lance Stephenson', 'Kyle Korver', 'Blake Griffin', 'Terrence Jones', 'Chris Paul', 'Shaun Livingston']", "['Joakim Noah', 'Wilson Chandler', 'Michael Kidd-Gilchrist', 'Lance Stephenson', 'Kyle Korver', 'Blake Griffin', 'Kris Humphries', 'Chris Paul', 'Jerryd Bayless']", "['Joakim Noah', 'Wilson Chandler', 'Michael Kidd-Gilchrist', 'Gordon Hayward', 'Joe Johnson', 'Blake Griffin', 'Andray Blatche', 'Chris Paul', 'Jerryd Bayless']", "['Joakim Noah', 'Wilson Chandler', 'Michael Kidd-Gilchrist', 'Gordon Hayward', 'Kyle Korver', 'Blake Griffin', 'Andray Blatche', 'Chris Paul', 'Avery Bradley']"]